# AppKit default URL handler

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, swift, appkit

What object is responsible for default URL handling in AppKit on OSX?

When I click on a link in NSTextField it opens in default application for the link. I would like to intercept this action in order to modify default behaviour (in particular, open some of the links in-app) without implementing this for every control in my app.

I know that NSTextView has a `clickedOnLink:atIndex:` delegate method that I could use, but I couldn't find a similar method for NSTextField, and I'd rather implement this without considering every control separately.